# ASP.NET MVC layer separation with SQL Dapper and NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dapper, n-tier-architecture

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application using SQL Dapper for retrieval and NHibernate for CRUD. I am facing some problems with layer separation.

I have repositories say UserRepository which has **public User GetUsersList()** method. Here "User" is an NHibernate entity. The problem here is I need to display a field in the UI which is not present as a property in User like 'HasAltContacts' which I am directly retrieving from an SQL query.

Now, my question is do I need to create separate DTO's and leave these NHibernate entities and build repositories (at least READ METHODS) around these classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here "User" is NHibernate entity. The problem here is I need to
>   display a field in UI which is not present as property in User like
>   'HasAltContacts' which I am directly receiving from SQL query.

Define a view model that will contain all the properties your view requires. Then have your controller action populate this view model by querying the various data sources you have and pass this view model to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is causing me confusion here, 'HasAltContacts' is not a field which I can get from db seperately or calculate it, to have it in ViewModel. It is part of the query which I am executing along with fields which match the properties of "User" entity in DAL Layer. There needs to be some property (which isn't part of User entity currently) to carry till MVC Application. My concern is, do we define another layer with these kind of DTO objects to pass on to MVC app?